# How to prove type equality inductively without classes?

Tags: haskell, types

I am trying to prove associativity of type-level lists in such a way that will allow me to convert between equivalent types without carrying around any constraints.

Assuming the standard definition of concatenation:

```hs
type family (++) (xs :: [k]) (ys :: [k]) :: [k] where
  '[] ++ ys = ys
  (x ': xs) ++ ys = x ': (xs ++ ys)
```

Suppose, I am given a function:

```hs
given :: forall k (a :: [k]) (b :: [k]) (c :: [k]). Proxy ((a ++ b) ++ c)
given = Proxy  -- Proxy is just an example
```

and I would like to call this function and then use associativity:

```hs
my :: forall k (a :: [k]) (b :: [k]) (c :: [k]). Proxy (a ++ (b ++ c))
my = given @k @a @b @c  -- Couldn't match type ‘(a ++ b) ++ c’ with ‘a ++ (b ++ c)’
```

This type equality is not trivial indeed, so it is not a surprise that the compiler doesn’t understand it, however I can prove it! Unfortunately, I don’t know how to convince the compiler that I can.

My natural first thought is to do something like:

```hs
proof :: forall k (a :: [k]) (b :: [k]) (c :: [k]). (a ++ (b ++ c)) :~: ((a ++ b) ++ c)
proof = _
```

and then change my function to:

```hs
my :: forall k (a :: [k]) (b :: [k]) (c :: [k]). Proxy (a ++ (b ++ c))
my = case proof @k @a @b @c of Refl -> given @k @a @b @c
```

But I still have to define `proof` and for this I need to perform induction on its type arguments. The only way to do induction on types in Haskell that I know is to define a type class, but I then I will have to add the corresponding constraint to the type of `my`, which I don’t want to do – the fact that it calls `given` and coerces the result is an “implementation detail”.

Is there any way to prove this kind of type equality in Haskell without resorting to unsafe postulates?

Comment: This would be a use case for dependent types, but Haskell does not have those. We need to resort to singletons (so that we can pattern-match and recurse), possibly through type classes. I don't think you can write a non-bottom term of type `(a++(b++c)) :~: ((a++b)++c)` without further singleton arguments or typeclass constraints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot prove this without a typeclass constraint, because it isn't true. In particular, here is a counterexample:

```
Any ++ ([] ++ []) -- reduces to Any ++ []
(Any ++ []) ++ [] -- does not reduce
```

To rule out the (stupid) existence of `Any`, you must use a typeclass that does not have an `Any` instance; no other choice.

Comment: Ah, right, I keep forgetting about `Any` :(. I was hoping that the kind annotations in my definition of `++` would guarantee it’s true, but `Any` clearly breaks this.

Comment: Isn't `Any` basically just `undefined` but at type level? Since it's morally correct to pretend the latter doesn't exist, why can't we do the same for the former?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Certainly, we can pretend all you like. And then the way that you convert your type-level pretense to the computation level is to use `unsafeCoerce`. But the question explicitly requests avoiding `unsafeCoerce`, and so we can't pretend after all.