# Why can't ghc match these types on this Category product?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, category-theory, gadt

I have a pretty typical definition of a category as such:

```
class Category (cat :: k -> k -> Type) where
  id :: cat a a
  (.) :: cat a b -> cat c a -> cat c b
```

Now I would like to make the [Product Category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/product+category) so I made this GADT

```
data ProductCategory
  (cat1 :: a -> a -> Type)
  (cat2 :: b -> b -> Type)
  (x :: (a, b))
  (y :: (a, b))
  where
MorphismProduct :: cat1 x x -> cat2 y y -> ProductCategory cat1 cat2 '(x, y) '(x, y)
```

Now this compiles nicely, my issue arrives when I try to make this an instance of `Category`.  The math here is really easy, it seems like this should be a simple instance.  So here is what I come up with:

```
instance
  ( Category cat1
  , Category cat2
  )
    => Category (ProductCategory cat1 cat2)
  where
    id = MorphismProduct id id
    (MorphismProduct f1 f2) . (MorphismProduct g1 g2) = MorphismProduct (f1 . g1) (f2 . g2)
```

But this comes up with an error:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘a2’ with ‘'(x0, y0)’
      ‘a2’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          id :: forall (a2 :: (a1, b1)). ProductCategory cat1 cat2 a2 a2
        at src/Galaxy/Brain/Prelude.hs:175:5-6
      Expected type: ProductCategory cat1 cat2 a2 a2
        Actual type: ProductCategory cat1 cat2 '(x0, y0) '(x0, y0)
    • In the expression: MorphismProduct id id
      In an equation for ‘id’: id = MorphismProduct id id
      In the instance declaration for
        ‘Category (ProductCategory cat1 cat2)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        id :: ProductCategory cat1 cat2 a2 a2
          (bound at src/Galaxy/Brain/Prelude.hs:175:5)
    |
175 |     id = MorphismProduct id id
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've spent a long while on this error and I just don't know what it is trying to communicate to me. It claims that it can't match `a` to `'(x0, y0)` but I have no idea why, it seems like it really should be able to.

What is the issue that is being encountered here?  How to fix it would be nice but I would really like to know how to read this message.

Comment: I think I am piecing together what is wrong here.  I have the implicit assumption that `'(x, y)` is a exhaustive case for `a :: (k, j)`, however this assumption might not be so easy for the compiler to recognize. For example `'Just x` is not an exhaustive case for `a :: Maybe k`.

Comment: Yep, got it in one. There are a couple duplicates around of this question. You can add that principle as an axiom by `data IsTuple (v :: (a, b)) = forall (x :: a) (y :: b). v ~ '(x, y) => IsTuple; isTuple :: forall (v :: (a, b)). IsTuple v; isTuple = unsafeCoerce IsTuple` (thereabouts), and I think it's even safe. It will give you very strange equalities if you abuse type families (think `type family F :: Bool -> Bool -> (Type, Type)`; you will get `F b1 b2 ~ '(x, y)`), so GHC doesn't have it by default, but I don't think it actually breaks anything.

Comment: If you define `type Cat ob = ob -> ob -> Type` the kind of `ProductCategory :: Cat ob1 -> Cat ob2 -> Cat (ob1, ob2)` becomes clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` should have type `forall a. MyCat a a` but in this case you can only construct `forall x y. MyCat '(x, y) '(x, y)`. Generalizing that further requires the assumption that all pairs `a :: (t1, t2)` are of the form `a = '(x, y)`, which is not provable in Haskell.

One workaround is to not use a GADT; in particular, don't refine the type parameters in the constructor. Instead of this:

```hs
data ProductCategory cat1 cat2 a b where
  Pair :: cat1 x x' -> cat2 y y' -> ProductCategory cat1 cat2 '(x, y) '(x', y')
```

do this:

```hs
data ProductCategory cat1 cat2 a b where
  Pair :: cat1 (Fst a) (Fst b) -> cat2 (Snd a) (Snd b) -> ProductCategory cat1 cat2 a b

type family Fst (a :: (k1, k2)) :: k1 where Fst '(x, y) = x
type family Snd (a :: (k1, k2)) :: k2 where Snd '(x, y) = y
```

Note that definition of `ProductCategory` is equivalent to this, without GADT syntax:

```hs
data ProductCategory cat1 cat2 a b
  = ProductCategory (cat1 (Fst a) (Fst b)) (cat2 (Snd a) (Snd b))
```

Comment: I have a nagging suspicion that this just kicks the stone further down the road – ok, now you can easily create `Pair` values, but they don't contain the knowledge that the objects are actually tuples. What if somebody _using_ the category would like to have that knowledge at hand? Wouldn't they then need to resort to the `IsTuple` axiom trick anyway, that HTNW mentioned in the comments?

Comment: "the assumption that all pairs `a :: (t1, t2)` are of the form `'(x, y)`, which is not provable in Haskell." Doesn't the existence of [`Any`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:Any) mean that not only is it not provable, but that it's not true?

Comment: @leftaroundabout That's fair. My answer just says that you don't need that knowledge for this construction. Of course there are limits to what you can do in Haskell, or really any language. So I prefer to see these questions as a challenge, "how far can we get in Haskell?" rather than "well this looks like it will need full dependent types at some point, so let's not even try".

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica just it make sense to... _reason_ with `Any` at all? That's basically just a void pointer / bottom value, isn't it? We also don't usually worry about `undefined :: (Int, Int)`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Good question. Although `Any` is often brought up as a counterexample, I'm actually hesitant to accept it as such because `Any` is really just "stuck". That fact on its own is not sufficient to contradict the proposition that tuples are all made with the tuple constructor. I could be missing some other fact about `Any` though.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Isn't that basically what [How to prove type equality inductively without classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61130588/7509065) is about? Do you agree with its answer?

Comment: Yes I would question that answer to be pedantic, but given that Haskell doesn't have formal semantics for "true" and "false" to fully make sense, we could be generous and read "it's not true" as "it's not true in all conceivable models, and the example of `Any` is very strong evidence of that fact".

Comment: @leftaroundabout IIRC, it's not just `Any`, but also about open type families like `type family T a b :: (a, b)` which can not be converted to a specific pair.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica No, because you don't know what `Any` is; the point is it hasn't been defined. As such, GHC never assumes that a stuck type family is apart from any type; it is neither true that `Any` is different from `'(,)` nor is it true that it is `'(,)`. Adding that axiom that all pairs are made from `'(,)` just forces that `Any` *is* `'(,)`. It fixes an unknown. As @Li-yaoXia says, this invalidates certain models of the theory, but the theory itself should still stand.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Note that the answer to your linked question says `Any` is different from other types because the asker wanted to avoid creating axioms. Without axioms, it *appears like* `Any` is inequal to everything else (though it *isn't actually*), and so you may as well act like it. Allowing `unsafeCoerce` as I suggested lets you "disagree" (except there isn't anything to disagree with) and say that it actually is equal to existing types, and that doesn't contradict anything, because that statement was neither true nor false.